# Word for cases of things satisfying a property

Tags: soft-question

I'm not sure if this is the place for this but I don't have anyone nearby and I've been blanking on the word for a while.

If you have a property P, and some families of things that exhibit that property, but you also have a few other cases that exhibit the same property but don't belong to any family, what are these few other cases called? I suppose a term one can use is "sparse" but I had in mind a different word.

Comment: The finite simple groups that don’t fit into one of the larger classified families are called “sporadic”

Comment: There is the medical term "idiopathic": a condition having no cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two such words are "exceptional" and "sporadic", used e.g. in the contexts of Lie algebras and groups.

Comment: Exceptional! That's the word I was looking for, thank you so much.